# Understanding UIKit, Storyboards and underlying frameworks

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I’ve started with the App Development with Swift a few weeks ago. I liked it because it was a mix of Swift and Xcode and UIKit.

I studied C and C++ in uni and I also had an intercourse with C# that gave me some kind of an idea of an interface builder. In no ways I dived deep into it but it was C code, and it was quite clear how to edit and do stuff in code.

The problem is, the book mentioned above does not explain anything about UIKit or Storyboards in depth. But more like at all. You are editing classes, you are writing functions that magically get called at certain events, but most of this is invisible. It just works (but it’s not a positive thing here unfortunately). I have no idea how to do these things programatically.

UIKit is complex and I find it a quite confusing. It seems to go against the basic coding that I did before in C (terminal stuff). My minimal C# experience gives me a few ideas but that’s just not enough.

Is there any good place where I can start off? Swift is fine, so I’m not really interested in that.

Comment: What about the many Apple developer documentation pages, good books, Ray Wenderlich turorials, ...  There's a lot just seconds away using google. So what have you found so far? This is a too broad question, really.

Comment: Indeed, there are dozens of them and I have no idea what is the best.

I believed that this was a common problem for people coming to Swift and Xcode. I guessed there must be a go-to book/site that is worth the time.

Comment: It's good to start with Apple's documentation. You could also just start developing and learn from seeing how things fit together.

Comment: Asking for a suggestion as to books or tutorials is off the topic here.

Comment: Plus, "I also had an intercourse with C#" hm.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, if you're serious with iOS development, I strongly suggest you get a hold of this book, it's really worth the money.

```
http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920055211.do
```

And to your questions:

1. UIKit is a built-in framework in iOS, in which important UI elements (Views and Controls) are implemented.
2. XCode is an IDE just like Eclipse and Visual Studio.
3. A storyboard itself is where you implement the the UI of your app (which can also be done via coding). Storyboards offer many powerful tools for you to conveniently design your UI visually, and see how the screens in your app looks like.